# Firebase google auth automatically selecting user. How to force it to select account

Tags: firebase, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication, google-signin

If in any browser, when i am logged in with single google account and try to invoke 'sign in with google' option on firebase, it is automatically logging-in to firebase with the already logged in account. It gives me no option to login with a different account.
This happens only if one account is logged in browser. Multiple accounts doesn't create this problem.
So, it is any way I can force users to choose accounts everytime they click 'sign in with google' button?

Answer (score 51):

This worked for me: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/gxBm0WKCuIY

```html
var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
provider.setCustomParameters({
  prompt: 'select_account'
});
```

Comment: This works only for web. What about cordova. I am using 
const googleCredential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(response.idToken);
          firebase.auth().signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(googleCredential)
.

How to use here prompt here ?

Comment: For all custom parameters you can take a look here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#authenticationuriparameters

Comment: @Anand_5050 maybe take a look here, using a slightly different flow: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/cordova#handle_the_sign-in_flow_with_the_firebase_sdk. There you can use the provider.

Answer (score 7):

For those initiating a Google Sign In from mobile, when instantiating your sign in object, you can simply use the [revokeAccess](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInClient#public-taskvoid-revokeaccess) method to force the account picker to be displayed

```
googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, googleSignInOptions)
googleSignInClient.revokeAccess()
```

Comment: `googleSignInClient.signOut()` should be enough

Answer (score 1):

If you're authenticating the user credential [Using Google Sign-In with JavaScript](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin), try to remove the follow line of code:

```
provider.addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login');
```

After you clicked the sign in button, it will allow you to select a Google account that you want to use.

Comment: I tried as you said above. But, nothing changes. I see the account information on the top right even earlier. What i need is, no matter how many accounts are linked to the browser at that instance, it should definitely ask the user to pick / add an account.

Answer (score 0):

when you logs out call this method -

```
GoogleSignIn().signOut();
```

This is enough