# Firebase Auth Google - always ask for account

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I recently implemented a google sign in. It works fine, but there's one thing bothering me.

When the user logs in for the first time, a window is being opened for the user to login in google and choose his account. But when the user logs out and tries to login via google again, **somehow his previous login is being remembered** and he's just getting logged in.

**How can I achieve to ask for google login each time a user chooses to log in via google?**

That's how I log the user out:

```
 try! Auth.auth().signOut()
```

Login:

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error?) {
    if let error = error {
        print("Failed logging into Google: ", error)
        return
    }

    print("Successfully logged into Google.")

    guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
    let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken,
                                                   accessToken: authentication.accessToken)

    Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (acc, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Failed to create User with Google: ", error)
            return
        }

        let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        databaseRef.child("users").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            if snapshot.hasChild("\(uid)") {
                print("Data found.")
                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileViewController") as! ProfileViewController
                vc.readLeasing()
                vc.readData()
            } else {
                self.upDataToDatabase(from: user)
            }

        })

        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

        logInViaGoogle = true
        defaults.set(logInViaGoogle, forKey: "logInViaGoogle")

        print("Successfully created user with Google.")
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using google sign in or firebase sign in ?

Comment: @MayurKarmur Google Sign In provided by Firebase Auth

Comment: You should implement your code with `do...try...catch`, so you can find error what exactly issue with `signOut()`.

Comment: @MayurKarmur See edit for Login - the user is being logged out successfully, as in the Auth.currentUser is going to be nil. But smh the Google User is being remembered.

Comment: May be because of this, `defaults.set(logInViaGoogle, forKey: "logInViaGoogle")`. Are you set false on sign out?

Comment: @MayurKarmur Yes, issue has already occurred before adding this.

Answer (score 2):

As poited in [Firebase google auth automatically selecting user. How to force it to select account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39032255/firebase-google-auth-automatically-selecting-user-how-to-force-it-to-select-acc)

you can just do

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
provider.setCustomParameters({
prompt: 'select_account'
});
```