# How to select a Gmail account to log in Firebase on Mobile apps using vue for a multiplatform app

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, google-oauth, google-authentication

I'm working on a multiplatform app (iOS and Android) that I'm using a `.vue` view to do the authentication on Firebase from both platforms using Gmail.

I'm using Google as a provider:

```js
provider = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()
firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
```

The problem is that I'm always being asked to fill the email and password, but I'd like to just select one of the Gmail accounts that are already registered on the phone.

**I'd like to have a Gmail selector (as below), how can I achieve it?**

[image: Desired behavior - just select one Gmail account]

But I'm getting the screen to type my email and password to be able to log in:

[image: Actual Behavior - need to input the Gmail and password]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this has been answered from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43727675/11138585).

Just add a `prompt` for the user to `select_account`

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
provider.setCustomParameters({
  prompt: 'select_account'
});
```