# Firebase google auth automatically selecting user. How to force it to pop up gmail accounts

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I want to let the user select his gmail while loging in second time but it is taking previous one and not letting the user change his gmail.

[Firebase google auth automatically selecting user. How to force it to select account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39032255/firebase-google-auth-automatically-selecting-user-how-to-force-it-to-select-acc)

This question explains my problem correctly but the solutions given are outdated (I think).

I'm working on react-native android app.

here is my code for sign in and sign out

```
    login: async () => {
      try {
        // Get the users ID token
        const {idToken} = await GoogleSignin.signIn();

        // Create a Google credential with the token
        const googleCredential =
          auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken);

        /* auth.GoogleAuthProvider.setCustomParameters({
          prompt: 'select_account', //setCustomParameters is not a function(Error says)
        }); */

    // Sign-in the user with the credential
        return auth().signInWithCredential(googleCredential);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    },

    logout: async () => {
      try {
        await auth().signOut();
        // await GoogleSignin.signOut(); //not working
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
    },
```

There is not proper article on how to use setCustomParameters() in this case.

Note: sometimes it is asking to select gmail when more than one account is logged in(that too rarely).

I want to show popup to change(add another) gmail even when one account is logged in.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Thank you.

Comment: Most likely you signed in to the app before with this specific Google account, and the approval you gave at that point is maintained. If forcing the account picker doesn't work, you can also unlink the Google account from your app as shown in *this* specific answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69125373/209103

Comment: GoogleSignin.revoke() not working
GoogleSignin.signOut() not working

Answer (score 3):

Finally this worked for me in signout function.

```
await GoogleSignin.revokeAccess(); // added now
await auth().signOut();
```