# Firebase Google login: Is it possible to use a provider instance in signInWithCredential?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm building a Chrome extension in JavaScript, where I'm using Firebase authentication with Google:

```
  const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(null, token);
  try {
    const myUserCredentials = await signInWithCredential(
      auth,
      credential
    );
```

Since I'm running this in an extension, I cannot use `signinWithPopup` because window is not defined.
Using `signInWithCredential` works fine, but what I'm trying to achieve is to have the users select their Google account each time they login, but Firebase unfortunately remembers them and automatically use the latest account.

I saw that you can create a new instance of Google provider and tell Google to show the user account selection:

```
  const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
  provider.setCustomParameters({
    prompt: 'select_account',
  });
```

But then if I have that instance, how can I use it with the function `signInWithCredential`?

Something totally different I tried was to revoke the user auth token with a GET request to "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=myToken", but then revoking the user token will just show again the consent popup with the exact same remembered email

Comment: The client remembers the permission to use Google auth with the app. You can revoke that as shown in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69125373/209103

Comment: Hello Frank thanks for your answer, I couldn't find how to import GoogleSignIn, isn't it only for Android? I should have mentioned I'm building a Chrome extension in Javascript, thanks in advance